# Show only first Instance of string in Summary Search? (hide Duplicates)

Tags: sql, netsuite

I have a summary search in Netsuite which outputs categories of items from transactions;

[image: Search Results]

What I want to do, is only show the first instance of each category.
So that the list as seen here would show;

- ARTWORK, CAN HOLDERS,
- ARTWORK
- ARTWORK, POLOS,
- ARTWORK
- ARTWORK
- ARTWORK
- ARTWORK
- ARTWORK, POLOS

So that the duplicated values do not appear.
My current code for this column is;

```
REPLACE(NS_CONCAT({custitem_category}), ',', ', ')

Field: Formula (Text) 
Summary Type: MINIMUM
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, by adding `DISTINCT` within the `NS_CONCAT` expression, it gives me the results I was after;

```
REPLACE(NS_CONCAT(**DISTINCT** {custitem_category}), ',', ', ')
```

Gives

- ARTWORK, CAN HOLDERS,
- ARTWORK
- ARTWORK, POLOS,
- ARTWORK
- ARTWORK
- ARTWORK
- ARTWORK
- ARTWORK, POLOS

(without duplicates)